# Reading missing files to DVC

Tags: dvc

A ran into problem with DVC when some files are missing in remote. For example when I execute `dvc pull` I get the output

```
[##############################] 100% Analysing status.
WARNING: Cache 'c31bcdd6910977a0e3a86446f2f3bdaa' not found. File 'data/2.mp4' won't be created.
WARNING: Cache '77186c4596da7dbc85fefec6d0779049' not found. File 'data/3.mp4' won't be created.
```

`dvc status` gives me:

```
data/2.mp4.dvc:
    changed outs:
        not in cache:       data/2.mp4
data/3.mp4.dvc:
    changed outs:
        not in cache:       data/3.mp4
```

It seems that `2.mp4` and `3.mp4` where added under dvc control but `dvc push` has not been executed.

I have access to the original mp4 files and I have tried to add them back. I copied the mp4 files to the data folder and executed:

```
dvc remove data/2.mp4.dvc
dvc remove data/3.mp4.dvc

dvc add data/2.mp4 
dvc add data/3.mp4
```

But there is no effect. How can I remove files from under dvc control and add them again?

Answer (score 1):

It seems I found a solution. I copied mp4 files to the data folder and executed commands:

```
dvc add data/2.mp4 
dvc add data/3.mp4

dvc push
```

Comment: Did you intend to add file by file? It is possible to `dvc add {directory}`.

Comment: Glad that you've found a solution! I've noticed that you have dvc file per each mp4 file, which makes me think that you've added your data dir with dvc add data -R, instead of adding it as a whole with dvc add data.

Comment: The difference between those is that when you are using dvc add data, dvc will track the whole directory, so if you add or remove anything to/from data, it will be able to detect that. Also, in that case only one dvc file is created for the whole directory. And if you are using dvc add -R data, it will go through the whole data directory recursively and will add every and each file to dvc creating a separate dvc file, so if you ever add a new file to data, dvc won't be able to tell.

Which dvc version are you using, btw? We've recently added a warning to help avoid that confusion.

Comment: @don_pablito Thank you for advice! I’ve intentionally added files separately because I’m total newbie with DVC and I wanted to learn how to deal with files first.

Comment: @RuslanKuprieiev My DVC version is 0.40.7